# How to retrieve information about locked accounts

Tags: command-line, security, users

Is it possible to retrieve info regarding to locked unix accouts?
I am interested in seeing information about what date and time the lockout happend and from what hostname (pc name). I would like to see something similar to the `who` command.

Comment: Under what unix variant?

Comment: It's under SunOS 5.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this information is kept anywhere. They only place you could get some of this type of information would be from the `sudo` command logs, assuming you're using `sudo` and that your `sudo` setup gives out permissions such that you're logging on individual commands such as passwd.

I've used this command before to show what accounts are locked,i.e. "LK".

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 1 | awk '{ system("passwd -S " $0) }'
root PS 2010-12-18 0 99999 7 -1 (Password set, SHA512 crypt.)
ftp LK 2010-11-11 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
nobody LK 2010-11-11 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
usbmuxd LK 2010-12-18 0 99999 7 -1 (Password locked.)
avahi-autoipd LK 2010-12-18 0 99999 7 -1 (Password locked.)
dbus LK 2010-12-18 0 99999 7 -1 (Password locked.)
ntop LK 2011-05-22 0 99999 7 -1 (Password locked.)
nginx LK 2011-08-19 0 99999 7 -1 (Password locked.)
postgres LK 2012-06-26 0 99999 7 -1 (Password locked.)
fsniper LK 2012-06-26 0 99999 7 -1 (Password locked.)
clamupdate LK 2012-08-31 0 99999 7 -1 (Password locked.)
```

#### Alternative method

Thanks to @RahulPatil in the comments here's a more concise method:

```
$ awk -F: '{ system("passwd -S " $1) }' /etc/passwd
root PS 2007-06-20 0 99999 7 -1 (Password set, MD5 crypt.)
bin LK 2007-06-20 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
daemon LK 2007-06-20 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
adm LK 2007-06-20 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
```

Comment: `awk -F: '{ system("passwd -S " $1) }' /etc/passwd`